# latex/beamer export depending on system

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am using org files to organize my research projects. I am using org both on Linux and Windows. While I am exporting org files to LaTeX or Beamer, a link to a local file on Windows starts with `[[C:\Users\MYSELF\Document\org...][Text]]`, whereas a link to a same synced local file on Linux starts with `[[/home/MYSELF/local/docs/org....][Text]]`.

I thought that `#+MACRO: docs_path system_specific_docs_heading` can do the job but it expands only on specific locations and not replacing this in links. I tried and write a function hooking on `rg-export-filter-latex-fragment-functions` but it did not replace strings in the link definitions either.

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to make these change in the link definitions automatically when I am exporting to the LaTeX/Beamer.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer requires that you write some lisp.]

I think the best way is to define your own custom link type. The idea would be to have a single org file that could be processed on either of the two systems and the export would treat the link type differently. For example the link `[[sysdep:foo][foo]]` would be exported as `\href{file:///windows-sys-doc-path/foo}` on the windows system, but as `\href{file:///linux-sys-doc-path/foo}` on the linux system.

For that you would need to add the link type:

```
(org-link-set-parameters "sysdep"
                         :store 'org-sysdep-store-link
                         :export 'org-sysdep-export
                         :follow 'org-sysdep-open)
```

and then provide definitions for the three sysdep functions.

Look in the `contrib/lisp/org-man.el` for an example of how to provide a custom link type for man-pages and see if you can define the functions above. The general idea for each function would be to check the variable `system-type` which tells you what type of system the emacs instance is running on (the value is a symbol - two examples are 'gnu/.linux and 'windows-nt but there are many others - see the documentation of `system-type` for all the possibilities). Then based on the value of that variable, each function would do different things.

Not a complete answer by any means, but I hope it's helpful. And maybe others will chime in with different methods.

Comment: Thank you so much Nick. I ended up writing a function to do 'replace-match' that is called by 'org-export-before-processing-hook with different strings for each system. Your solution seems more elegant and I will definitely try your suggestion.